# Ignoring android library bin files in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: android, svn, tortoisesvn, android-library

I have two Android projects, Project A and Library Project B.

Project A uses B as a [Android Library](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject).

Both projects are committed to the same SVN repository and for the most part everything works.

However, the bin directory of Project A continually gets flagged as Updated by TortoiseSVN.  It seems like the .svn directories are getting copied from Project B's source directory to Project A's source directory.
This isn't interfering with my repository or project setup at all, but it is really annoying to have Tortoise always saying my project is not committed when it in fact is.

Is there any way around this issue?  I already added the bin directory to the ignore list, so I don't know why it's even showing up.

Comment: +1 this has been bothering me for a while >< hope you find an answer!

Comment: What build environment are you using (e.g. Eclipse, IntelliJ, plain Ant, ...?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same problem and finally I solved it!

Suppose PrjA <- lib proj, PrjB <- project that referrencing PrjA

1. add PrjA/gen , PrjA/bin to svn ignore
2. add PrjB/gen, PrjB/bin to svn ignore
3. in PrjB's project properties, remove .svn of PrjA from build path.
   ( Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Source > PrA/src > excluded > ****/.svn/*

Hope this workaround works for you.

Answer (score 1):

use [.svnignore](http://www.devcha.com/2008/02/how-to-make-svn-ignore-some-folders.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through the Explorer GUI - look for Tortoise SVN -> Add to ignore list.

[Ignoring Files and Directories in Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html)

Comment: My apologies! Do you know what's copying the .svn from B to A?